# Pipenv install package with exact latest version

Tags: python, pip, pipenv

When I run `pipenv install requests` it will add the following to Pipfile:

```
requests = "*"
```

But I want pipenv to add the latest package to Pipfile as a fixed (*hard-coded*) version that is exact or compatible:

```
requests = "=={latest_version}"
# or
requests = "~={latest_version}"
```

The problem with `requests = "*"`, is that it causes pipenv to **accidentally upgrade the package to the latest version** (which might cause compatibility issues) when relocking (for example when installing a new package).

With node running `npm install axios` will add a fixed (compatible) version:

```json
"axios": "^0.21.1" // compatible
```

---

Currently, I have to go to the `https://pypi.org/project/requests/` to determine the latest version and then run `pipenv install requests=={latest_version}`. Further version updates are managed by dependabot.

Comment: isn't the default behaviour that the latest version is installed (as long as it is compatible)?

Comment: @FlyingTeller, yes but it it is not fixed (`requests = "*"` can be any latest version in the future), I want pipenv to add it as exact by default.

Answer (score 4):

You may try:

```
pipenv install requests~=1.2
```

Comment: And how would you know it's `1.2`? ;)

Comment: @nezort11 if you're in the pipenv shell, you can just run pip freeze and check requests version but I agree there should be a way to do what you asked in your op.

Answer (score 4):

This isn't currently possible (as of writing this comment). You can upvote/check https://github.com/pypa/pipenv/issues/5531 to see the status of the issue.

Comment: While this link may answer the question, it is better to include the essential parts of the answer here and provide the link for reference.  Link-only answers can become invalid if the linked page changes. - [From Review](/review/late-answers/33940904)